# How do I Convert DateTime.now to UTC in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I have `d = DateTime.now`, how do I convert 'd' into UTC (with the appropriate date)?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

<strike>`d = DateTime.now.utc`</strike>

Oops!

That seems to work in Rails, but not vanilla Ruby (and of course that is what the question is asking)

```
d = Time.now.utc
```

Does work however.

Is there any reason you need to use `DateTime` and not `Time`? `Time` should include everything you need:

```
irb(main):016:0> Time.now
=> Thu Apr 16 12:40:44 +0100 2009
```

Comment: Because I want the correct date for the conversion, ie, for GMT +10 can be ahead the next day...

Comment: Time will do that for you just fine. Time includes the date part as well, not just the time of the day. Do Time.now.inspect to take a look.

Comment: Oh sweet.  So whats the difference between Date, Time and DateTime then?

Comment: Time is stored internally as the number of seconds and microseconds since the epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC. Date, internally, is represented as an Astronomical Julian Day Number, and DateTime is just plain weird (which is probably why Rails overrides it)

Answer (score 182):

```
DateTime.now.new_offset(0)
```

will work in standard Ruby (i.e. without ActiveSupport).

Comment: And this is actually the most correct answer to the question.

Comment: This should have more upvotes. DateTime is different to Time. I needed exactly this.

Comment: `new_offset` method argument defaults to `0` already. So `DateTime.now.new_offset` may be used as well.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the DateTime class doesn't have the convenience methods available in the Time class to do this. You can convert any DateTime object into UTC like this:

```
d = DateTime.now
d.new_offset(Rational(0, 24))
```

You can switch back from UTC to localtime using:

```
d.new_offset(DateTime.now.offset)
```

where `d` is a DateTime object in UTC time. If you'd like these as convenience methods, then you can create them like this:

```
class DateTime
  def localtime
    new_offset(DateTime.now.offset)
  end

  def utc
    new_offset(Rational(0, 24))
  end
end
```

You can see this in action in the following irb session:

```
d = DateTime.now.new_offset(Rational(-4, 24))
 => #<DateTime: 106105391484260677/43200000000,-1/6,2299161> 
1.8.7 :185 > d.to_s
 => "2012-08-03T15:42:48-04:00" 
1.8.7 :186 > d.localtime.to_s
 => "2012-08-03T12:42:48-07:00" 
1.8.7 :187 > d.utc.to_s
 => "2012-08-03T19:42:48+00:00"
```

As you can see above, the initial DateTime object has a -04:00 offset (Eastern Time). I'm in Pacific Time with a -07:00 offset. Calling `localtime` as described previously properly converts the DateTime object into local time. Calling `utc` on the object properly converts it to a UTC offset.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, works in Ruby：

```
DateTime.now.to_time.utc
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set an ENV if you want your `Time.now` and `DateTime.now` to respond in UTC time.

```
require 'date'
Time.now #=> 2015-11-30 11:37:14 -0800
DateTime.now.to_s #=> "2015-11-30T11:37:25-08:00"
ENV['TZ'] = 'UTC'
Time.now #=> 2015-11-30 19:37:38 +0000
DateTime.now.to_s #=> "2015-11-30T19:37:36+00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

In irb:

```
>>d = DateTime.now
=> #<DateTime: 11783702280454271/4800000000,5/12,2299161>
>> "#{d.hour.to_i - d.zone.to_i}:#{d.min}:#{d.sec}"
=> "11:16:41"
```

will convert the time to the utc. But as posted if it is just Time you can use:

```
Time.now.utc
```

and get it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, it can be much easier to start from a time if you're dealing with `now` and need timezone precision.

```rb
Time.now.utc.to_datetime
#<DateTime: 2023-11-13T02:16:03+00:00 ((2460262j,8163s,564598000n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

You can then easily manipulate this UTC DateTime and convert it back to a simple time as needed:

```rb
now = Time.now.utc.to_datetime
# => #<DateTime: 2023-11-13T02:17:26+00:00 ((2460262j,8246s,2810000n),+0s,2299161j)>
truncated = DateTime.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, 0, 0)
# => #<DateTime: 2023-11-13T02:00:00+00:00 ((2460262j,7200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

This can be useful because DateTime's API is a bit more ergonomic in some ways. Highly recommend looking over the full class documentation for these, you might discover some very handy conversion and timezone methods you might not have known about:

- [DateTime](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/datetime)
- [Time](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/time)
- [Date](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/date)

For example both `Time` and `DateTime` has a `#zone` instance method that will return the timezone you selected (if you specified one) or the `ENV["TZ"]` if it was set:

```rb
ENV['TZ'] = nil
# => nil
Time.now.zone
# => "PST"
```