# How can I remove the zone from a DateTime value?

Tags: ruby

I have this DateTime:

```
=> Fri, 03 Feb 2012 11:52:42 -0500
```

How can I remove the zone(-0500) in ruby?
I just want something like this:

```
=> Fri, 03 Feb 2012 11:52:42
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Time always has a zone (it has no meaning without one). You can choose to ignore it when printing by using [`DateTime#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime):

```
now = DateTime.now
puts now
#=> 2012-02-03T10:01:24-07:00

puts now.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
#=> Fri, 03 Feb 2012 10:01:24
```

See [`Time#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for the arcane codes used to construct a particular format.

*Alternatively, you may wish to [convert your DateTime to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755669/how-do-i-convert-datetime-now-to-utc-in-ruby) for a more general representation.*

Comment: Not at all! DateTime (which isn't the same as Time) stores calendar information only and does not need to point specific point in time. Therefore unspecified time zone makes sense in some cases. For instance, http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 (form #1).

Comment: @skalee I think you may be mistaking the [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class with the [`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) class. The former has calendar information only, the latter includes time (which must be associated with a time zone). Consider the output of `DateTime.new(2016,5,5).to_s #=> "2016-05-05T00:00:00+00:00"`, where the `+00:00` at the end indicates that this is midnight _**in GMT**_ (e.g. London), not midnight in Denver, CO.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the accepted answer you can also add the same `strftime` parameters to `DATE_FORMATS` a Rails hash allowing you to standardise output formats in your application.

In `config/initializers/datetime_formats.rb`:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:nozone] = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Then in your code you could do:

```
Time.zone.now.to_s(:nozone)
```

You could even make it the default:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
Time.zone.now.to_s
```

There is also a separate hash for dates:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%a, %d %b %Y'
```

This feature has been around for years but appears to be little known.

Comment: This one is better.

Answer (score 3):

When all else fails

```
zoned_time = Time.now
unzoned_time = Time.new(zoned_time.year, zoned_time.month, zoned_time.day, zoned_time.hour, zoned_time.min, zoned_time.sec, "+00:00")
```

Comment: `zoned_time.strftime("%Y").to_i,...`. can be accessed more easily (and probably more efficiently, since it doesn't involve string parsing) with `zoned_time.year, zoned_time.month,` etc.

Answer (score 1):

PhilT has a great answer, but here's an alternative FOR RAILS. With Rails you can put this into your locale files. Here's an example of specifying various formats.

```yaml
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"
      no_timezone: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"
      long: "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"
      short: "%d %b %H:%M"
      time_only: "%I:%M%p"
      military_time: "%H:%M"
```

Then in your code, use `I18n.l(DateTime.now, format: :no_timezone)`. You could similarly just set the default format to exclude the timezone.

Comment: The question is a ruby specific question, not a rails question.