# formatting datetime variables for conditional statement

Tags: ruby, datetime

Having trouble using two datetimes variables in a conditional statement.

Here is an example output of variable one. Lets call it **ontime_datetime**:

> Fri, 10 Feb 2017 16:30:00 +0000

Here is an example output of variable two. Lets call it **delivery_timestamp**:

> Fri, 10 Feb 2017 13:15:00 -0600

I need to compare these two variables and find out which value is greater by date and time:

```
if delivery_timestamp <= ontime_datetime
      f.update_attributes(on_time: true)
      puts "#{f.tracking_number}       ONTIME"
elsif delivery_timestamp > ontime_datetime 
      f.update_attributes(status_refund: true)
      puts  "#{f.tracking_number}       NOT ONTIME"

else
      f.update_attributes(other_result: true)
      puts "#{f.tracking_number}       OTHER"
end
```

When I run my script the second conditional is met, but the value of
delivery_timestamp is before ontime_datetime, so the first conditional
***should*** be met. I think it has something to do with the timezone value? (which I don't need but not sure how to remove)

Either that, or I need to format the variable better for this type of
conditional.

**Added later by DK for more info ----**
Here is how I am getting **ontime_datetime**:

```
json_response = JSON.parse(response)
              transit_time = json_response['TrackPackagesResponse']['packageList'][0]['standardTransitTimeWindow']['displayStdTransitTimeEnd']
              transit = json_response['TrackPackagesResponse']['packageList'][0]['standardTransitDate']['displayStdTransitDate']
              transit_date = Date.parse Date.strptime(transit, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
              transit_datetime = "#{transit_date} #{transit_time}"
              ontime_datetime = DateTime.strptime(transit_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
```

...and here is how I am getting **delivery_timestamp**:

```
delivery_timestamp =  info_track[:delivery_timestamp]
```

The output value is the same format between ontime_datetime and delivery_timestamp, but the conditional evaluation isn't working properly.
Any help (via code demonstration) would be great!

Please advise - 
DK

Comment: Are you comparing the values as Strings or as DateTime objects? (The latter is definitely preferable)

Comment: Good question. I'm getting the value of 'delivery_timestamp' from an xml response: delivery_timestamp =  info_track[:delivery_timestamp]. And ontime_datetime is being formatted like so:  ontime_datetime = DateTime.strptime(transit_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"). Appears I'm using a string and datetime variable which...so that's probably the issue?

Comment: I would definitely verify their types and make them both true DateTime objects if possible. Comparing two different types against each other sounds like a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like timezone is relevant for time, but if you're positive you don't need them: [check out strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132337/how-can-i-remove-the-zone-from-a-datetime-value)

Answer (score 0):

Conditional is working properly. Both variables need to be in the same DateTime format which mine was not.