# Ruby - time.now in UTC

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Convert DateTime.now to UTC in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755669/how-do-i-convert-datetime-now-to-utc-in-ruby)

How do I get current time in Date-time-milliseconds & UTC? 
Ex. 2012-03-22T18:48:40.873Z

I tried -

```
Time.now.utc_offset.to_s
Time.now.xs_datetime
```

Comment: `Time.now.utc`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755669/how-do-i-convert-datetime-now-to-utc-in-ruby

Comment: You want `Time.now.utc`. [This post][1] was the guide to my answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755669/how-do-i-convert-datetime-now-to-utc-in-ruby

Comment: Got it - Time.now.utc.xmlschema

Comment: A Ruby newbie like me might end up with this: `Time.utc(*Time.now.to_a)`

Comment: But how do I get those milliseconds?
I need it exactly in this format and UTC - 2012-03-22T18:48:40.873Z

Comment: @Firstname: Have a look at [`Time#strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime), which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nik. It is kind of confusing, how do I write for the format I need?

Comment: @Firstname: It's all there in the documentation (along with a few examples), I won't write the format string for you (though it will probably start with `%Y-%m-%dT...`). Also for the future, if you want to ping people (so they get notified about your answer), use an @ character before the name :)

Comment: How about an answer? Just that line of comment would give you at least 25 points :-) ...

Comment: @mliebelt,  is right. Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ") worked. But my bigger prob is still there. :/
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881633/ruby-rails-savon-soap-digest-auth-issue#comment12603604_9881633](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881633/ruby-rails-savon-soap-digest-auth-issue#comment12603604_9881633)

Comment: @mliebelt: Unfortunately I already passed the 200rep mark, so those 25 points would be wasted ;)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`Time.now.utc` is what you must be using.

Comment: For ISO 8601 use `Time.now.iso8601` which results in `2016-10-25T09:13:31+00:00`

Comment: Actually, use `Time.now.utc.iso8601` to get UTC: `2016-10-25T09:13:31Z`