# 1 hour difference with rails time in postgres prepared statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the problem, that doing a query in rails converts the the wrong time in the generated postgres sql statement.
The time in the shell, ruby and postgres is 23:32, but in the generated sql statement it is 22:32

Any Ideas whats wrong? I Use rails 3.2.11, pg gem 0.14.1 (installed with bundle install)

debian system time:

```
$ date
Sat Feb  9 23:32:10 CET 2013
```

in ruby:

```
1.9.2p290 :004 > Time.now
=> 2013-02-09 23:32:15 +0100
```

in postgres:

```
=> select current_time;
   timetz       
--------------------
23:32:24.213487+01
(1 row)
```

generated rails query:

```
1.9.2p290 :003 > Item.where "next_crawling_at < ?", Time.now
Item Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (next_crawling_at < '2013-02-09 22:32:17.935595')
```

Comment: [This related answer may be of help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have set UTC time zone in your client - even though that seems to contradict your result from `Time.now`. What do you get for `Time.zone`?

Without the additional DST-offset for summertime (since we have winter now), your time zone is probably CET (Central European Time), while `Time.now` seems to be translated to UTC.

You could force a particular time zone in Ruby with [`Time.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Paris")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300493/convert-utc-to-local-time-in-rails-3) - (or whatever time zone name fits the time zone setting of your DB).

Or you can force UTC timestamps with [`Time.now.utc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755669/how-do-i-convert-datetime-now-to-utc-in-ruby) and append `AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` in Postgres.

Or you operate with `timestamp with time zone` everywhere.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.
Time.zone result:

    Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.11)
    1.9.2p290 :001 > Time.zone
     => (GMT+00:00) UTC

Comment: @agreif: Explains it, doesn't it?

Comment: Now the problem is, that im my rails app I can set datetime values myself, (where I could provide timezone info), but rails also automatically maintains the created_at/updated_at columns automatically, that is done in the rails framework so that I cannot influence it. Is there a way to set it globally in rails, so that I can simply use bla_time = Time.now; model.save!

Comment: @agreif: I'm an expert with Postgres, but only an amateur with Rails.

Comment: I understand, thanks. I found a good article on the rails timezone stuff here: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails