# Why is Ruby's DateTime.new_offset not in rdoc

Tags: ruby, datetime, rdoc

I wanted to create a [`DateTime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) instance for the UTC time zone using the answer from [this SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866504/814576) that uses the method `DateTime#new_offset(0)`. However, I am not able to find its definition in either the `DateTime` rdoc or the rdoc of its parent class [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html). Yet, `DateTime` indeed has the method defined:

```
DateTime.method_defined? :new_offset # => true
```

There must be a good reason why `new_offset` is not appearing in the rdoc.

Answer (score 2):

***Why does `DateTime#new_offset` not appear in RDoc of `DateTime`?***
Because it is defined in the parent class `Date`.

***Why does `Date#new_offset` not appear in RDoc of `Date`?***
Because it is a private method in class `Date` (for obvious reasons, as, a `Date`-object does not have a Time-portion and, thus, no Timezone) and private methods do not appear in RDoc.
[Compare definition in Ruby/ext/date/date_core.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L9424)

***Why is `#new_offset` defined in class `Date` instead of `DateTime`?***
This is the actual question that can only be answered by a Ruby core developer.
I can only make an assumption here:
In the C-definition `date_core.c` that includes the definitions of both, class `Date` and class `DateTime`, two C-structs are defined, `SimpleDateData` and `ComplexDateData`, mirroring the Ruby-classes in question, where `ComplexDateData` contains all fields that `SimpleDateData` contains. The only reason for the two structs seems to be memory-usage in order to have a `Date`-object taking up less memory than a `DateTime`-object. Other then that, all functions are written to work with both structs and have not been duplicated, which makes sense for obvious reasons (eg. code-maintenance), especially as both structs are based on the same logic of how dates are represented internally.
[Compare how most functions check the internal data-type with: if (simple_dat_p...](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L1609)
Particularly the function `dup_obj_with_new_offset` is a C-function that is also used by functions of the (later) Ruby-class `Date`, eg. method `#httpdate`, and (probably for this reason) is attributed to class `Date`.
[Compare RDoc for Date#httpdate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-httpdate)
Like other functions, `d_lite_new_offset` relies on duplicating the given object (struct) and, thus, on `dup_obj_with_new_offset`. For this reason, `d_lite_new_offset` is potentially also attributed to `Date`.
Surely, there would have been another way to outline the C file, but the outcome for the Ruby classes would not be different and, I assume, that is why nobody sees a reason to change the current outline.

***Why does `DateTime#new_offset` not appear in RDoc of `DateTime`?***
Returning to the original question, I summarize, that there are two things that I do not understand and, thus, cannot explain: I have no idea why...

1. the script that creates RDoc for ruby-doc.org is written in a way that does not pick up all public methods of a class independently of how they have been defined. `DateTime#new_offset` is not the only example of forgotten methods; there a lots of others. In `DateTime` alone there are a few, eg. `#hour`, `#min`, `#sec_fraction`. All these methods are public methods for `DateTime`-objects but don't appear in any RDoc...
   [Compare definition of DateTime methods](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L9609)
2. for indexing, there are not at least some method stubs in these classes that help the RDoc script to pick up all public methods.

Answer (score 0):

It defined in Date class. Here is definition from the sources:

```
# d.new_offset([offset=0])  ->  date
#  
# Duplicates self and resets its offset.
# 
#    d = DateTime.new(2001,2,3,4,5,6,'-02:00')
#                              #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06-02:00 ...>
#    d.new_offset('+09:00')    #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T15:05:06+09:00 ...>
def new_offset(p1 = v1)
    #This is a stub, used for indexing
end
```

Comment: From which version is this?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784)

Comment: But it isn't in the Date rdoc either